# javascript - Delete paragraph which contain specific text inside

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have paragraph as below and I want to remove the paragraph which is contained text "do".

Do nothing.

I do not know.

Try something.

Catch me, if you can.

I expect the result is

Try something.

Catch me, if you can.

Vanilla javascript, not jQuery. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is not a code request site. The main idea is to understand problems and solve issues with the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you might want something like this:

```
els = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(let i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  if(els[i].innerHTML.includes('do')){
    els[i].parentElement.removeChild(els[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(let i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
    {
       // remove toLowerCase if you want case sensitive.
       if (p[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf('do') != -1)
       {
          p[i].remove(i);
       }
    }
```

the above code should achieve what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function upd(){

    const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p')

    ps.forEach(function(p){
        if (p.textContent.toLowerCase().includes('do')) {
            p.remove()
        }
    })
 }
```

```html
<p>Do nothing.</p>
<p>I do not know.</p>
<p>Try something.</p>
<p>Catch me, if you can.</p>

<h4>I expect the result is</h4>

<p>Try something.</p>
<p>Catch me, if you can.</p>

<button onClick="upd()">update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all the paragraphs containing 'the'. Just a very basic example how to do this.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>todo-app</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <h1>This is our todo-app</h1>
    <h2>Hello there!</h2>
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph the 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph the 4</p>
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
  <script src="todo-app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

todo-app.js

```
const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
ps.forEach(p =>{
  if (p.textContent.includes('the')){
    p.remove();
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to say you have

tag for each line you specified in post,

then you can follow,

```
$("p").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf("do") != -1)
     $(this).attr("hidden", true);
// Or you can remove, by accessing parent element and remove this from the 
parent

})

})
```